# fullpage change scrollingspeed on specific sections

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

When I init fullpage.js I use the function below. But is there a way to change the scrollingSpeed on specific sections?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({

    //Navigation
    anchors:['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21'],
    navigation: false,

    //Scrolling
    css3: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 700,
    autoScrolling: true,
    scrollBar: false,
    easing: 'easeInQuart',
    easingcss3: 'ease',
    loopBottom: false,
    loopTop: false,
    loopHorizontal: true,
    continuousVertical: false,
    scrollOverflow: false,
    touchSensitivity: 15,
    normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 15
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `setScrollingSpeed` provided by fullPage.js.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setscrollingspeedmilliseconds):

> **setScrollingSpeed(milliseconds)**
>
> Defines the scrolling speed in milliseconds.

```
$.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(700);
```

Then using the callback `afterLoad` or `onLeave` you can set the speed back to the one you want for the sections you want.

Answer (score -1):

If u want to have specific speed to specific sections, you have to declare some ID's on the section.The Idea is to seperate your different sections and to initialize them all seperate. Then you can do this:

```
$('#YourSection').fullpage({

    //Navigation
    anchors:['some anchors'],
    navigation: false,

    //Scrolling
    css3: true,
    scrollingSpeed: your specific speed,
    autoScrolling: true,
    scrollBar: false,
    easing: 'easeInQuart',
    easingcss3: 'ease',
    loopBottom: false,
    loopTop: false,
    loopHorizontal: true,
    continuousVertical: false,
    scrollOverflow: false,
    touchSensitivity: 15,
    normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 15
});
```